# Intent to Reset Android Application, xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app that has a couple of SharedPreferences that are saved to the device. My issue is that I would like to delete these preferences from a Preference inside a PreferenceScreen (an android settings page). Is there any xml-based android intent that will reset the shared preferences? Using the intent tag? If not, is there a way to create my own intents programmatically and reference them in the xml?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can clear your preferences from anywhere by using [Editor#clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear())

Comment: I need to clear my preferences from the xml using the <intent> tag, because the Preference tag I am using does not have an onClick attribute for me to reference and use Editor.clear () within the Java file

Comment: Here is the tutorial I was using

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: I've never used preferences this way, but it's seems logical assumption that you are using default shared preferences, which can be acquired from `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`.

Comment: Yes that's what I was using. In one of my activities I store it using that method and the Editor, and then on this separate page I want to delete them. This is also the only data stored on the app, so if it's easier to reset the app to default, that would be acceptable too